# I am having troubles reading text into an array, what do I need to change in this code?

Tags: java, arrays

This is my current text file that I am trying to read from:

```
Buffalo
Montreal
Boston
Ottawa
Toronto
```

Whenever I run this code, my 5 elements of my array print as "null", so somehow I am not storing the information into the array properly. Here is the code I have so far! (I am using the Ready To Program IDE)

```
// The "Hockey" class.
import java.awt.*;
import hsa.Console;
import java.io.*;

public class Hockey
{
    static Console c;           // The output console

    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        c = new Console ();

        //setting up file reading
        FileReader fr = new FileReader ("cities.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (fr);

        //initialising array
        String cities[] = new String [5];

        //loop to read in the 5 entries
        for (int i = 0 ; i > cities.length ; i++)
        {
            cities [i] = br.readLine ();
        }

        //loop to print all elements of "cities" to the console
        for (int i = 0 ; i < cities.length ; i++)
        {
            c.println (cities [i]);
        }
            // Place your program here.  'c' is the output console
    } // main method

} // Hockey class
```

Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: i > cities.length should probably be i < cities.length in your first for loop.  Also: Go Montreal!

Answer (score 3):

Your for loop has an incorrect condition.

```
//loop to read in the 5 entries
for (int i = 0 ; i > cities.length ; i++) //reads as (i greater than cities.length)
{                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    cities [i] = br.readLine ();
}
```

The above should be: `i < cities.length;`(i less than cities.length)

The loop isn't running, which explains why your array isn't populating.

Comment: You should accept @Trobbins answer to help others looking for unanswered ones. And welcome to the site!

Comment: @Daniel No need '@' me, I'm the author of the answer, so I'll automatically get a notification. Just FYI :)